# Where's kprinter in Lucid?

Tags: 10.04, printing

I've been using `kprinter` for several years as a way to give programs that don't have fancy print dialogs (like `gvim`) a fancy print dialog. From a command-line sense it looks a lot like `lp` or `lpr`, but it pops up a GUI for choosing printers and setting printing option (eg: duplex, pages per side, page ranges, etc.).

I can't find `kprinter` on my system since upgrading to Lucid. What package is it in?

If it's been permanently removed (as seems to have happened with a few other things I used to use) is there a good alternative? I found `gtklp`, which is passable, but doesn't seem quite as nice as `kprinter`.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Kubuntu? KDE or Gnome?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. I mostly use Gnome, but I use a few random KDE apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kprinter is not found in Lucid because "Kprinter obviously has been removed from KDE4" 
Source: [kprinter tool missing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-kde/+bug/595072)

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative that's better than gtklp?

Comment: Hi Laurance; I do not deal with printing that much. I use the GUI coming with Ubuntu as default. Its very well integrated with the applications we use. It's a GNOME component I believe. I don't know a printing tool other than that. Don't you like it?

Comment: What do you mean "the GUI coming with Ubuntu as default"? I'm looking for a tool that provides a nice GUI for selecting printers and setting print options to applications that just expect to be able to pipe PostScript to an external command. That's what `kprinter` did, and it was great until it vanished. `gtklp` also does this, though the UI is nowhere as nice as `kprinter`. BTW: you should use at-replying in comments if you want the person you're talking to to get a notification. It took me almost a year to see your comment because I didn't get a notification about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install kprinter again by typing `sudo apt-get install kdeprint` in the Terminal and hitting Enter.

For more, please refer to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. The error I got was: "Package kdeprint is not available, but is referred to by another package."

Comment: That's actually the thread that made me aware of `gtklp`'s existence. That thread is from 2004, so it predates Lucid by quite a bit. The two alternatives to `kprinter` it mentions aren't as nice (though `gtklp` is much nicer than `xpp`).